# Lucene .NET frequency of IndexWriter commit

Tags: .net, lucene.net

I am writing many documents using an IndexWriter in Lucene .Net. Since there is a cost to committing the documents added I am wondering if there is an optimal number of documents to add before committing. Obviously too many and if there is a crash you risk losing everything in memory, too frequently like after every document is added throttles throughput.

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem like there is a performance hit until you reach a very high number.

```
Total time to commit [10] messages was [00:00:00.1093779]
Total time to commit [20] messages was [00:00:00.0156221]
Total time to commit [40] messages was [00:00:00]
Total time to commit [80] messages was [00:00:00.0312509]
Total time to commit [160] messages was [00:00:00.0156231]
Total time to commit [320] messages was [00:00:00.0156273]
Total time to commit [640] messages was [00:00:00.0312489]
Total time to commit [1280] messages was [00:00:00.0312509]
Total time to commit [2560] messages was [00:00:00.0500343]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is no good answer to this, seemingly simple, question. Other than "it depends"...

It depends on many things, like:

- How big is each document? If they are big (many fields, large fields) then the number will be quite small when a flush occurs
- What is the use-case? Do you bulk insert? If yes then a high value it "better", less IO = higher throughput. Do you require the doc to be committed/persisted/durable immediately. Then you should commit on every add/update. Lots of IO but if the frequency is low-ish. Then there's the infinite spectrum in-between.

You are better setting "setRAMBufferSizeMB" rather than "setMaxBufferedDocs". Limiting the amount of memory used makes the infrastructure demands more predicable. By default lucene flushes by memory size (default 16MB).

There is also another approach. Set the buffer size to a fairly high number. But also have a timer to commit periodically. This gives a balance between buffering and the period that you might "lose" updates.

Is there an incrementing "ID" associated with the doc? If so, make sure it's a field. Then on start up you can query for the most recent doc by doing a query with a Sort of the ID descending (like "select top 1 order by ID desc") and restart the updates from there.

If there's no ID then add a numeric date field and put DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks in it. This becomes your "update cursor".

The other thing to bear in mind is search latency. The amount of time between ingesting a doc and it being searchable. You can follow the NRT pattern and be almost completely up to date. But there is a cost. Or you can decide that some latency is acceptable. In this case you can make smarter decisions about when to refresh the Reader/Searcher.

More of a conceptual discussion. If you can give more details about the various concerns and parameters, I can be more specific.